# JavaScript: Email affecting the CSS of the other tags in the Web App

Tags: javascript, html, html-email, email

I have an Email client web app. The problem I am facing is whenever i render the HTML from the Email. Sometimes, the email may contain some classes that affect my web app design. Looking for Suggestions?

Comment: Use an `<iframe>`?

Comment: Use class `prefix` for your E-mail or App

Comment: @ChrisG iframe is not a good way to do it.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar Css is dynamic

Comment: @NencyGupta Why? Granted, Gmail doesn't use iframes, but my other email provider does (GMX). It's the simplest way to isolate the mail document from your app, and you can even scroll it. How is it not the perfect way to display an email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you use an iframe to display the emails like Chris G suggested in the comments,

or you could use something like Emogrifier (https://www.myintervals.com/emogrifier.php / https://github.com/MyIntervals/emogrifier) to converts all styles to inline-styles.

That would stop styles affecting your page but someone could still e.g. position an element somewhere on your page, so you may have to include additional checks.